# Error in selecting video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, userscripts, tampermonkey

I am using jQuery in a Userscript to select the video in this page:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B70bgg53J5zQMG15VWYwQ05MMFU/view

This is the script which I am running :

```
(function() {
   var exist = setInterval(function() {
   console.log('checking');

   if ($("video").length) {
     alert("Video is there !");
     clearInterval(exist);
   }
 }, 100);
})();
```

I added an interval to wait for the element to load up. But I can't select it.

I also used other selectors like : `"div.html5-video-container > video"` and `"video.video-stream.html5-main-video"`.

However nothing works. Guide me please !

Comment: Try to wrap your function in $(document).ready();

Comment: You need to run another instance of your userscript inside the iframe i.e. on `https://youtube.googleapis.com/embed/*` as you can see in devtools. That second instance will have access to the iframe contents and `video` element.

Comment: @wOxxOm I didn't even think that . It's working now. Thanks!